# Clojure deps.edn not resolving dependency

Tags: clojure

I am trying to add a dependency to `id.walt/waltid-ssikit` a `deps.edn`. However, when I download the dependencies, it cannot resolve all dependencies:

`Error building classpath. Unable to resolve org.webjars.npm/babel__highlight version: [8.0.0-alpha.1,9)`

It does work when I add the dependency to a `pom.xml`. Maven doesn't seem to try to resolve the missing webjar dependency.

I am having the issue when using this `deps.edn`:

```
{:mvn/repos
 {"waltid" {:url "https://maven.walt.id/repository/waltid/"}
  "waltid-ssikit" {:url "https://maven.walt.id/repository/waltid-ssi-kit/"}
  "jitpack.io" {:url "https://jitpack.io/"}
  "Maven central" {:url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"}}
 :deps {id.walt/waltid-ssikit {:mvn/version "1.2308021811.0"}}}
```

and

```
clj
```

It returns the error, while I was expecting it resolve all dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Clojure CLI -- using `org.clojure/tools.deps` for dependency resolution -- tries to pick the latest version available that satisfies the dependencies you request. This is generally good because it is less likely to lead to conflicts (assuming libraries make some effort to be backward compatible -- which Clojure libraries generally do).

Unfortunately, in this case, that allows it to pick `org.webjars.npm/babel__code-frame {:mvn/version "8.0.0-alpha1"}` which relies on a version range for `org.webjars.npm/babel__highlight` -- `[8.0.0-alpha1,9)` -- that *has not been released yet!*

The smallest change I was able to make to "fix" this was to add this dependency to your `:deps` map:

```
org.webjars.npm/babel__code-frame {:mvn/version "7.21.4"}
```

This pins `babel__code-frame` to `7.21.4` which makes it depend on a version of `babel__highlight` that has actually been released so at least you can get a program running.

Note: it may be that you'll have a mix of 8.0.0-alpha1 and 7.x versions of `org.webjars.npm/*` libraries which are not compatible. If that turns out to be the case, run `clojure -X:deps tree` and see what other `org.webjars.npm/*` stuff seems to be bringing in 8.0.0-alpha* versions and use https://search.maven.org to find earlier non-alpha versions to depend on.

Version ranges are terrible (but that `npm` stuff seems to be full of them).